# How to align one div to the left and other to the right. At mobile, the right one goes up and the left goes down

Tags: html, css

I want to make a nav footer and place a logo to the left and a dropdown box to the right. On mobile screens, the dropdown must goes up and occupies the full width. I already made a solution but not sure if it's a good one. [codepen](https://codepen.io/gabrielmlinassi/pen/WNbPaGL)

[This result I want to achieve (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1bmv.gif)

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="left-half">
    <h1>Left Half</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right-half">
    <h1>Right Half</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-half {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.right-half {
  grid-row: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }
  .left-half {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
    justify-self: start;
  }
  .right-half {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2;
    justify-self: end;
  }
}
```

After I find a solution I'll make it with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flexbox:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

You have to watch out for accessibility concerns, though. Moving the layout around with CSS can mess up keyboard tabbing on interactive elements. You will need to modify the tabindex value with JavaScript if you're using buttons or links for example.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ks8ymf/)

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

html and css code without using flex as flex may not support all devices:

Below is css:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
.right-half {
float: right;
width: 50%;
}
.left-half {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
.right-half h1 {
text-align: right;
}
}
```

Below is html:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="right-half">
    <h1>Right Half</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="left-half">
    <h1>Left Half</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```